# How to convert configs from jshint and jscs to eslint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint, eslint, jscs

I tried to use polyjuice tool for this task:

```
polyjuice --jshint .jshintrc --jscs .jscsrc > .eslintrc
```

It doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

What error message(s) are you getting?

To run Polyjuice from the command line, be sure to install the package globally:

`$ npm install -g polyjuice`

You should then be able to convert your [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/) rules to [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/) by running the following command in any directory that contains a valid config:

`$ polyjuice --jshint .jshintrc > .eslintrc`

Comment: I think, there wasn't any error message, but the behavior of **eslint** was different than before w/ **jscs** and **jshint** (that was my experience)